# Column Comment Section to Categorical Data as Seperate Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write code that uses a table of specific keywords to match data for multiple rows in a single column in a worksheet and categorize those matches as separate worksheets with all other associated data in the same workbook.

I have tried researching split code and parse code

```
Sub SplitData()
    Const lngNameCol = 2 ' Blue Sheet Issue
    Const lngFirstRow = 2 ' data start in row 2
    Dim wshSource As Worksheet
    Dim wshTarget As Worksheet
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngTargetRow As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wshSource = ActiveSheet
    lngLastRow = wshSource.Cells(wshSource.Rows.Count, lngNameCol).End(xlUp).Row
    For lngRow = lngFirstRow To lngLastRow
        If wshSource.Cells(lngRow, lngNameCol).Value <> wshSource.Cells(lngRow - 1, lngNameCol).Value Then
            Set wshTarget = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
            wshTarget.Name = wshSource.Cells(lngRow, lngNameCol).Value
            wshSource.Rows(lngFirstRow - 1).Copy Destination:=wshTarget.Cells(1, 1)
            lngTargetRow = 2
        End If
        wshSource.Rows(lngRow).Copy Destination:=wshTarget.Cells(lngTargetRow, 1)
        lngTargetRow = lngTargetRow + 1
    Next lngRow
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It only goes off column. Need to match it to specific key words. Trying to convert a column of comment section data (codes, abbreviations, words) to multiple worksheets.

Comment: It's not really useful to copy/paste an answer from elsewhere, without noting where you got it from, what you've tried in order to make it work, and exactly how it doesn't work for you as-is.  That code (written for some other problem) (1) doesn't help us understand exactly what you're trying to do (2) makes it more difficult for us to judge how to pitch any suggestions at the appropriate level of coding knowledge.

Comment: Thanks Tim Williams.. Apologies. In my research it was the closest code I could find to what I am trying to achieve. A code is needed to sort on a column to match a table of specifc words, if there is a match the code would copy that row with the match and place into a new worksheet labeled with the match word from the table.

Comment: OK but you need to add a little more detail - where is the table of words (on another worksheet?), which column needs to be checked, and does that column contain only single words, or larger pieces of text, etc etc.  It's difficult for people to provide you a starting point without some specific details.  Showing some sample data is always useful.

Comment: Thanks for your response Tim. So the table of words would be in a seperate sheet (labled 'legend') of the same workbook. Sheet1 is the data with columns A through J with column H needing to be matched against the words in legend. Column H is essentially a comment boxfor each row of data which has key words found in 'Legend'. When there is a match that row and other matched key word rows would be placed into a separate sheet.E.g.
Row 1 Column H contains: I found a cat and dog today.
New Sheet created labeled dog and contain Row 1 all columns and all other rows with dog in it-dog is in Legend

Comment: And you need to match on whole words (not eg cat <-> catalog) ?

Comment: Well this is the difficult part (i think), some abbreviations and words in column H are the same while others have a trailing S or a space or puncuation. I can do the data scrub on the front end if it makes the code easier to write/compile. Column H eg. ABC in legend and 'ABCs' or 'ABC;' in column H. I would need all rows with ABC to shift over to new worksheet. Hopefully that made sense and thanks again Tim for your responses, time, and effort

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic but will give you a starting point:

```
Sub SplitMeUp()

    Dim regEx As Object, rngWords As Range, rngComments As Range
    Dim w As Range, c As Range, sht As Worksheet, wb As Workbook

    'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ms974570(v=msdn.10)
    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    regEx.Global = True
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True

    'example ranges
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set rngWords = wb.Sheets("legend").Range("A1:A3")
    Set rngComments = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H2:H100")

    'loop over the list of words
    For Each w In rngWords
        Set sht = Nothing
        regEx.Pattern = "\b" & w.Value & "s?\b" 'word plus optional "s"
        'loop over the comments
        For Each c In rngComments.Cells
            If regEx.test(c.Value) Then
                'found a match
                If sht Is Nothing Then
                    'make sure there's a sheet to copy to
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set sht = wb.Worksheets(w.Value)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If sht Is Nothing Then
                        'no sheet already, so create one
                        Set sht = wb.Sheets.Add(after:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
                        sht.Name = w.Value
                    End If
                End If

                'copy the row over
                c.EntireRow.Cells(1).Resize(1, 10).Copy _
                    sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            End If
        Next c
    Next w

End Sub
```